# How to get the certificate part only and the private key part only respectively from PEM file in the command way?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, private-key, pem

Convert a PKCS#12 file (.pfx .p12) containing a private key and certificates to PEM, by, for instance:

`openssl pkcs12 -in cert_and_pvt_key.pfx -out cert_and_pvt_key.pem`

then I have a PEM file with both certificate and private key, now, I want to get certificate file and private key file respectively, yes, I know cert_and_pvt_key.pem is in text format, we can copy the key part and cert part as we like, but, this is not elegant, I want something sophisticated, like `openssl pkcs12`, is there anything available?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-nocerts` and `-nokeys` option to `openssl pkcs12` to only output the part you need.  Run `openssl pkcs12` with each in turn:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert_and_pvt_key.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

then:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert_and_pvt_key.pfx -nocerts -out pvt_key.pem
```

If you haven't got access to the original PKCS#12 file, then it becomes a little more difficult.  The following *should* work:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert_and_pvt_key.pem | openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

and:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert_and_pvt_key.pem | openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out pvt_key.pem
```

However, this asks for a pass-phrase when the the PKCS#12 is created and again when it attempts to split the file to certificate and keys.  OpenSSL provides the `-nodes` verb to disable this pass-phrase, but it doesn't seem to work with `-export`.  Therefore, it would fail in a script.

Otherwise, you're left with splitting the file with `awk` or similar.  There are plenty of examples on this site.

Comment: but I do not have cert_and_pvt_key.pfx, I only have cert_and_pvt_key.pem this one

Comment: Yes you do :-)  The example you have starts with a .pfx.  Don't convert it to a single .pem first, instead split it into two directly from the original .pfx file.

Comment: ya, I wish I have:-), someone keeps that pfx file, converted to pem, sent me that pem file,